# Git pull acting like git fetch?

Tags: git

For one of my company's repositories, the command `git pull` has started acting like `git fetch`. It pulls down all updates but does not actually merge the changes into the branch. I have to then run `git merge origin/master` to merge them.

What could cause this? I've never seen such behavior before. It doesn't seem to have affected other users of the repository, it's only me. It also hasn't affected other repositories I use. My git version is `git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)` and the repo is hosted on GitHub although I doubt that matters.

Edit with additional requested details:

The output of `git status` before any other action:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Followed by `git pull`:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 3333, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1623/1623), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (128/128), done.
remote: Total 3333 (delta 1517), reused 1554 (delta 1488), pack-reused 1710
Receiving objects: 100% (3333/3333), 2.07 MiB | 15.83 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2113/2113), completed with 355 local objects.
From github.com:repo/url
   6c1fab37s6b7..7acd6e422762  master                                            -> origin/master
```

`git status` after `git pull`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 94 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

For good measure, the output of `git branch -vv`:

```
$ git branch -vv
* master                                              6c32ab37afb7 [origin/master: behind 94] commit message
```

When using `GIT_TRACE=1`, this additional info is gleaned:

Before pull output:

```
09:46:36.847574 exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
09:46:36.848324 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git pull
09:46:36.865183 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok
09:46:36.870423 exec-cmd.c:139          trace: resolved executable path from Darwin stack: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git
09:46:36.871061 exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core
09:46:36.871707 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git fetch --update-head-ok
09:46:36.890545 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; ssh git@github.com 'git-upload-pack '\''org/repo-name.git'\'''
remote: Enumerating objects: 3232, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1480/1480), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (229/229), done.
09:46:41.239506 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git index-pack --stdin -v --fix-thin '--keep=fetch-pack 94201 on USERNAME' --pack_header=2,3232
09:46:41.252417 exec-cmd.c:139          trace: resolved executable path from Darwin stack: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git
09:46:41.254014 exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core
09:46:41.256304 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git index-pack --stdin -v --fix-thin '--keep=fetch-pack 94201 on USERNAME' --pack_header=2,3232
remote: Total 3232 (delta 1333), reused 1323 (delta 1243), pack-reused 1752
Receiving objects: 100% (3232/3232), 4.03 MiB | 19.39 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1972/1972), completed with 268 local objects.
09:46:42.117286 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
09:46:42.126065 exec-cmd.c:139          trace: resolved executable path from Darwin stack: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git
09:46:42.126771 exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core
09:46:42.127570 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
```

After pull output:

```
09:46:43.640301 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git gc --auto
09:46:43.647411 exec-cmd.c:139          trace: resolved executable path from Darwin stack: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git
09:46:43.648461 exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core
09:46:43.649426 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git gc --auto
```

Comment: Does it display any message or error? `git pull --rebase` is not the same as `git fetch` followed by `git merge origin/master` anyway.

Comment: Rebase and merge are different concepts. If you want to merge the branch you should remove `--rebase` from you command.

Comment: Read the documentation pages of [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).

Comment: Okay, everyone seems to have gotten hung-up on the `--rebase`. Let me clarify that whether or not I use `--rebase` the problem is the same, and that is unrelated. Running `git pull` does not merge the changes either and still requires `git merge origin/master`. I have edited the question. Links to the man pages are obviously not helpful in answering this, and are at best condescending. If you think the answer is there, quote or link to a specific part of the documentation. And no, there is no error or message beyond the normal listing of the new branches & commits it has retrieved.

Comment: "but does not actually merge the changes into the branch..." Why do you think that `git pull` does not actually merge? What evidence supports this? From what I can see in the output you give (`6c1fab37s6b7..7acd6e422762  master`) indicates that the merge is successful.

Comment: Do you see the part in the question that details the output of `git status` after `git pull`? What part of "Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 94 commits" tells you the merge was successful? I'm sorry I must be misunderstanding you or something.

Comment: @temporary_user_name Did you find the solution? Was it related to the old Apple version of git?

Comment: I did not. It remained a mystery. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Running `git pull` with no additional arguments is mostly equivalent to running:

```
git fetch
git merge
```

That is, there is no extra `origin/master` passed *to* `git merge` here.  So if you're on branch `br1` whose upstream is `origin/br1`, and you run `git merge`, you're effectively running `git merge origin/br1`, not `git merge origin/master`.

My *guess*, then—since you have not provided enough information in the question—is that whatever branch you are on right now, it has an upstream, but that upstream is not `origin/master`.  It would be best to show a `git status` command and its output before the `git pull` command and its actual output; these would help confirm which branch you are on when you run `git pull`, and what its upstream is set to.

Note that you can *configure* `git pull` to run `git rebase` as its second step, and in modern Git (but not that out of date Apple version) you will need to configure one of the `pull.*` settings as well.  I recommend not using `git pull` at all, though: run `git fetch`, then run your own second command.  Aside from the newest Git that requires the new `pull.*` settings, it's too easy to have `git pull` do things you didn't mean for it to do.

Comment: I have updated the question with the details you requested, namely the output of `git status` followed by `git pull` followed by `git status`. The situation you have described does not seem to be the case.

Comment: OK! That's very curious. Add `GIT_TRACE=1` to your `git pull` and let's see what Git is doing after it runs `git fetch`... we should get something like `trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok` followed by a bunch of stuff that includes the `master -> origin/master` line followed eventually by `trace: built-in: git merge FETCH_HEAD` for instance. If we don't get that, that's another clue in the debug tracing...

Comment: Strangely, setting `GIT_TRACE` didn't cause a change in the command output. It was the same as if it were not set. `echo $GIT_TRACE` does output `1`. I'm looking around for reasons why that would just....not work.....but not finding anything so far.

Comment: You could run `env GIT_TRACE=1 git pull` in case there's something weird about your shell, perhaps.

Comment: That worked, and you've again utilized a trick I was formerly unfamiliar with. You clearly have a decent amount of experience with this. I've edited the question with the output.

Comment: Even more interesting. It's run `git fetch` correctly and fixed a thin pack, and then it runs `git gc --auto` but never runs anything in between. That seems impossible since the last step of `pull` is to run either `rebase` or `merge` and it's the merge (or rebase) that runs `git gc --auto`. I don't know if Apple fiddled with something here though. You could try building Git from source (or using `brew`) to use a non-Apple-branded variant...

Comment: I keep coming back to the fact that it only happens in this one repository and not any other. If it was happening to all of them I'd reinstall git in a heartbeat but it just seems so strange to only be the one.

Comment: That is *really* odd, yes. If you want to keep plugging away at the debugging, I'd suggest doing `git config --list` for the repositories that work vs this one that doesn't and inspect everything that's different (most of which will be irrelevant, but maybe something matters), and/or using the system-call tracing facility (I forget which one macOS has, Linux has strace and BSD has ktrace) in case that offers clues that GIT_TRACE omits.